# Css break after specific div inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div like :

```
<div id="1" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 1</div>
<div id="2" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 3</div>
<div id="4" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 4</div>
<div id="5" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 5</div>
<div id="6" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 6</div>
```

So with this i have 6 div with horizontal align on the same line.

I want to break line after the second div, and after the fourth, i want :

```
My DIV 1 My DIV 2
My DIV 3 My DIV 4
My DIV 5 My DIV 6
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is `width:50%;` an option? Then it will start on a new line because there's no space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : add `<br>` after every odd `div`

```
$(function(){
    $('div:odd').after('<br>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhjLqu19/1/)**

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with pure css using `float: left` and clear float after 2n+1 like(or odd):

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin : 5px;
}
div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 1</div>
<div id="2" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 3</div>
<div id="4" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 4</div>
<div id="5" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 5</div>
<div id="6" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 6</div>
```

The above code is equal to:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 1</div>
<div id="2" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 3</div>
<div id="4" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 4</div>
<div id="5" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 5</div>
<div id="6" style="display:inline-block">MY DIV 6</div>
```

**References**

[:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Answer (score 1):

Inline-block elements flow along with any white space defined between them in markup.  Make sure there is no white space between the html <div> tags in your html markup.  Then, apply the following style.

```
div {width:50%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper around and give that a width and give the divs inside a width like this:

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">  
<div id="1" style="display:inline-block width='300px'">MY DIV 1</div>
<div id="2" style="display:inline-block width='300px">MY DIV 2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:inline-block width='300px">MY DIV 3</div>
<div id="4" style="display:inline-block width='300px">MY DIV 4</div>
<div id="5" style="display:inline-block width='300px">MY DIV 5</div>
<div id="6" style="display:inline-block width='300px">MY DIV 6</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
 width: 600px;
}
```